# How do I pass a R.drawable as a parameter so I can get images parsed

Tags: java, android

I try to save a unique image to each object but I get this error, how should the constructor look for it to work that way?
The constructor Beer(String, int, int) is undefined

```
m_beer = new ArrayList<Beer>();
              final Beer b1 = new Beer("Tuborg", 7, R.drawable.tuborg);
              final Beer b2 = new Beer("Carlsberg", 7, R.drawable.carlsberg);
              final Beer b3 = new Beer("Urquel", 9, R.drawable.urquel);


public class Beer 
{
    //Members
    private String name;
    private int color; //1 = Very dark 10 = Very light
    private R.drawable icon;

    //Methods
    public Beer(String name, int color, R.drawable icon)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getColor()
    {
        return this.color;
    }
    public void setColor(int color)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public R.drawable getIcon()
    {
        return icon;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
final Beer b1 = new Beer("Tuborg", 7,context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tuborg));
```

and like said before:

```
public Beer(String name, int color, Drawable icon)
```

Or you can send the int as parameter:

```
final Beer b1 = new Beer("Tuborg", 7, R.drawable.tuborg);
```

and:

```
public Beer(String name, int color, int icon)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(icon);
}
```

Comment: getDrawable() depricated in api 22

Answer (score 0):

public Beer(String name, int color, Drawable icon)

Comment: And: private R.drawable icon; should be private Drawable icon;

Answer (score 0):

You can use context's getDrawable() to implement that. In my case it worked.

```
my_signature_element.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_round_signature, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

If what i understand from your question is true then i think your aim is to add drawable image as a parameter if thats what you want
then you should add the

```
  @DrawableRes int image
```

like

```
public Beer(String name, int color,@DrawableRes int icon)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.icon = icon;
}
```

as your parameter then you can add drawable files in here